# PHP what are the effects of - cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 - in php.ini on a webserver (wp)

Tags: php, wordpress, ini

At my server , the host provide some alternative PHP.ini configs .

The only one that has the Extension Zip (which I need) is described as :

> zip_cgi.fix_pathinfo
>
> Advanced settings for experienced users with: cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1 and
>   Extension Zip Enabled

I am using the website primarily for wordpress , but I would like to know what are the possible effects (or meaning) of this .

from : http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo

> Provides real PATH_INFO/ PATH_TRANSLATED support for CGI. PHP's
>   previous behaviour was to set PATH_TRANSLATED to SCRIPT_FILENAME, and
>   to not grok what PATH_INFO is. For more information on PATH_INFO, see
>   the CGI specs. Setting this to 1 will cause PHP CGI to fix its paths
>   to conform to the spec. A setting of zero causes PHP to behave as
>   before. It is turned on by default. You should fix your scripts to use
>   SCRIPT_FILENAME rather than PATH_TRANSLATED.

searching for google provided only blurry results for me ,as well as directly asking the host (the call center girls do not really understand , and the tech guys are not responsive ..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the ZIP extension expects the URL to be passed along as a PATH_INFO variable. CGI and FastCGI implementations of PHP do not have PATH_INFO available, so when trying to pass the URI along, PHP fails. One way around that is to set cgi.fix_pathinfo to true.

Comment: SO in other words, tgat particular pathinfo fix is neccessary for the ZIP extention to work.. But does it have any possible side effects ?

Comment: Well according to this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6 `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1` poses a security risk, but I still don't know what the risk is

Comment: @simON: If you have an image with embedded malicious PHP code, and upload it through a site that accepts images, to say `/wordpress/content/image/badpicture.jpg` And then try to navigate to `/wordpress/content/image/badpicture.jpg/FakeFile.php`, the PHP interpreter will get called, guess that you meant to run `badpicture.jpg` since it contains PHP code, instead of `FakeFile.php` which doesn't exist, and then you have bad PHP code that can do whatever PHP can do- ie a compromised server.

Comment: @Nick, nice explanation. But I think this security risk only exists on Nginx. If Apache is used as the web server, it should be OK. Am I right?

Comment: @skyfree if apache uses php as mod_sapi and not as fastcgi

Comment: @Nick, that is no longer a security risk with php 5.3.9+, security.limit_extensions would not execute the .jpg file.

Comment: @Avibodha: Do you have a reference URL for that?  I'm looking for something authoritative with an explanation.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php, see security.limit_extensions, made for this reason. php will only run files with these extensions. here's the bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55181